# Is Hydrated Bloc good for storing more complex data?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm a newbie in flutter and recently started learning Bloc with flutter_bloc package. I want to store some data in local storage.

I have found the hydrated_bloc package, and here comes my question: "Is HydratedBloc good to store more complex data (like: users list, their details, saved todos, notes etc.) Or it's just created to persist simple state data (like: chosen theme (dark or liqht), last page where user left)?".
How can I best store data localy when using bloc?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use it to store complex data. Because, As the package itself states that it is built on top of **hive** for a platform-agnostic which is faster than shared preferences.

You can take a look at the image below to see the difference.

[image]